# Adding objects of different classes inherited from a single class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, linked-list

I want to store objects of two different classes inherited from a single class in a **linkedlist**.

Code example

```
class Animal {
     .....
     .....
     .....
}

class Dog  extends Animal {
     .....
     .....
     .....
}

class Snake extends Animal  {
     .....
     .....
     .....
}
```

Now what I want to do is something like this:

```
Linkedlist <Animal> animalslist = new Linkedlist <>();

animalslist.push (new Dog);

animalslist.push (new Snake);
```

> When I code like this for my **Android** app,  it builds successfully but when I run the app it crashes.

Comment: And what is an exception on crash? Maybe it is not because of inheritance?

Comment: Don't know about the exception but the problem is somewhere in adding objects of different classes into a same list. 
Thanks

Comment: Nothing possible to say without details about crash... Maybe you need to specify what type of objects in List instance? `new LinkedList<Animal>()` maybe something wrong in constructors... Who knows...

Comment: @vadim also tried that, but same results

Comment: my closest assumption is that somewhere in the code you try to treat object of class Dog as object of class Snake and you get a ClassCast exception. When you add to the list object of different classes you must not use any of them as actual implementation, but only as declared parent class or interface (i.e. `Animal`). If you still need to cast object from such list to actual class you have to have check its casting first, to be sure that you can cast it... Still you have to use debugger and see what and where actual exception is.

Answer (score 0):

Just for illustration to @Steamwork: 
code below works perfectly, even  ClassB and ClassA are not related to each other at all...

```
public class TestItMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();

    list.add(new ClassA());     
    list.add(new ClassB());

    System.out.println(((ClassA)list.get(0)).val1);
    System.out.println(((ClassB)list.get(1)).val2);
  }

  public static class ClassA
  {
    public int val1=1;
  }

  public static class ClassB
  {
    public int val2=2;
  }
}
```

@geekFromPeshawar - this example is a confirmation that your problem is not about List (or LinkedList). Problem is somewhere else...
It could be a problem because you use a `push` method. It actually shifts all objects down. And object class at each position may changes after each push. Work with `push` must be very careful.
 IMHO for such situation it is much better to use `add` method when added objects stay in place...

Comment: I've also tried it with add() method. But still not working

Comment: Do not try anything, find real cause of problem first. Otherwise you will never find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing is, as you rightly stated, because of the fact that you are trying to add different classes into the same list.

Normally, in Java, when you create a `List` capable of storing some class, such as `List<Animal>`, that does not mean that lists of Dogs or Snakes would have the aforementioned list as their parent:

```
// These two lists do not share a relation: one is not inherent of the other
List<Animal> animalList = new LinkedList<>();
List<Dog> dogList = new LinkedList<>();
```

However, there is hope:
If you were to create another class that makes use of the child classes of `Animal`, and resultantly use that in the `List`, you would be able to access an instance of each class for each `List` element:

```
class myClass {
    Dog dog;
    Snake snake;
}
// You can then add the class
List<myClass> myList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Furthermore, you can set the specific data for each `Dog` or `Snake` beforehand. Therein, each `myClass` object added to `myList` will contain all necessary data that can then be accessed later.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Any other way to store the objects of Dog and Snake inherited from Animal in a single data structure????

Comment: @Steamwork - your statement is not correct. Because if it is right and I have a `List<Object>` I will not be able to add there any objects because their actual classes are not Object. In real, I can add there any object of any class even not inherited one from another, just because all of them are children of Object.